# There are one or more errors on the page error show

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, app-store-connect

I have uploaded an app to iTunes using xCode. I have also changed version.
But when I click on 'Submit for review' than I am shown "There are one or more errors on the page" error, and also shown the red error in Build which show 'Submit your builds using Xcode 6 or later, or Application Loader 3.0 or later.'

I have upload app from xCode 7.

Can Anybody help me?

Comment: You need the select build which you want to be reviewed from the list of build there.

Comment: Actually I have upload build, but it show "1.0 (processing)" in hidden form. Not perfectly show.

Comment: Wait until processed, after that you need select build and then only you can submit for review.

Comment: It may take 10 - 30 mins. Some times it will take more time it may depend on the build.

Comment: My build is 5.0Mb but i have wait of 5 hours.

Comment: Is it showing the status "processing" or it is not showing in 'Activity' section?

Comment: iTunes Connect is down from afternoon, I too faced same issue. Now it works fine. Actually it won't take that much time.

Comment: @HariMohan I am also facing same issue with Xcode 9 ! Did you got any solution ?

Answer (score 1):

You need the select build which you want to be reviewed from the list of build there.
More details check [submit your build](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/SubmittingTheApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH33-SW1)

Comment: In my case I can't see Build list in spite of successfully loading app using xcode nor I am seeing "+" symbol besides to Build option